# Get List Item ID for file in Document Library

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, ajax

I've got a document library which has folders in it. I can get a given folder and iterate through the documents in the folder via REST just fine. What I need to do is get some of the list item properties (CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, Modified date) for each of those files.

I understand that what I need to do is to query the file as if it were a list item, using:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')/files(id)?
```

But I'm not seeing any way to get that list item ID for that file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('listName')/items?$select=ID"
```

It should work.

Thanks,

Raj.

Comment: Doesn't that return all items? I need to get the ID of the specific item for the file in question I already have.

Comment: You can add filter attribute to filter the query, for example if you would like to filter by ID of 4 then you can use below REST query.

`"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=ID&$filter=ID eq '4'"`

Comment: That's the problem- I've got the file, not the list item, so I need to get the ID of the list item the file is attached to.

Comment: In that case you can use any other associated field whose value you know. for example to filter based on title of the document you can use below REST query.
`"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=ID&$filter=title eq 'documenttitle'"`

Answer (score 0):

CreatedBy and ModifiedBy are `SP.People` fields. So you need to use expand in your query.

```
https://<siteURL>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/FolderRelativePath')/Files('<File Name>')?$select=Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor
```

FolderRelativePath : `'/sites/sitename/RootFolderName/SubfolderName'`

Author: internal name of the 'Created By' column

Editor: internal name of the 'Modified By' column

Hope this helps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider the file as an item then pass the file at the end of restApi endpoint:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')/items(id)/file?
```

Exanple

```
$.ajax({
url:"/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Document_Test')/items(8)/file?$select=*,Author/Title&$expand=Author",
type: "GET",
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
success: function (data){
console.log(data.d)
},
error: function (err){
}
});
```

Good luck